# Gradient descent extended function example

Tags: python, function, numpy, math, gradient-descent

Here is my gradient descent code:

```
import numpy
def gradient_descent(func, grad_func, w_init, n_epochs=100, lr=0.001, verbose=0):
    
    i = 0
    w = w_init
    while i < n_epochs:
        
        delta_w = -lr * grad_func(w)
        w = w + delta_w
                
        if verbose > 0:
            print("f={}; w: {}".format(func(w), w))

        i += 1    
    
    return w
```

Now the example that was explained to me is with simple function i.e:
`f(p,q) = p^2 + q^2`.
The partial derivates are in vector: [2p,2q] and that is clear.
The code for that function and its gradient is:

```
def f(w):
    return numpy.sum(w*w)

def grad(w):
    return 2*w
```

So the calculation goes:

```
# starting point
w_init = numpy.array([10,10])

# learning rate
lr = 0.1

# apply gradient descent
w_opt = gradient_descent(f, grad, w_init, n_epochs=25, lr=lr, verbose=1)
```

My problem is calculating it for another function such as: **`f(p,q) = (p^2 + 2q^3)`**. I know the values for partial derivative, but how to implement those values to this particular code?
How to write new function **f** and gradient function **grad** for it and to compute it with main function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're looking for something like this:

```
def f(w):
    return w[0] ** 2 + 2 * w[1] ** 3

def grad(w):
    return np.array([2 * w[0], 3 * w[1] ** 2])
```

Comment: Excately, that works. Thanks